# How is /proc/net files generated in Linux/Unix?

Tags: linux, networking, proc

I'm working on a network monitor for Linux, without packet sniffing.
I'm planning to read the network statistics and related data from /proc/net files.

I know that /proc is the mount point of process file system which is a virtual file system that reflects the kernel internal data structure.

I like to know how is it populated and is it possible to read the OS internals directly.

Comment: This is rather off-topic, but the answer is that it's a virtual FS set up by the kernel.  Just a structure in memory that behaves like a file system.  You can use the kernel interfaces directly - check the kernel docs.

Comment: But how will these files get populated, which process is populating these files..?

Comment: The kernel changes the data structure as it runs, and that makes it appear as though the virtual files are changing.   There aren't actually files on any "real" filesystem.

Comment: Yes but how is these files getting populated

Comment: Being a virtual filesystem, it is populated dynamically by the kernel. In regards to the implementaion, I would recomed to look at one of the existing tools, e.g.: https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/Diamond/blob/master/src/collectors/network/network.py